# debugging Spark application running on EMR

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, emr

I have the sequence of Spark job connected via Luigi and running on S3 on 30 machines cluster (15GB RAM each) which regularly hang on various stages. Today it was when processing 5 GB of data. The stage takes already 3,5h

This stage which hangs is just simple processing of data and later groupByKey on dataset of pairs (user id, 1L) and reduceGroups to get user events counts.
Even if some user has 1m events (unlikely because previously after filtering bots max was 300K) there shouldn't be 7 partitions on a single node taking 3 hours when rest finished.

Any idea?
Maybe the problem is that we use datasets which are still experimental?
How can we debug it?[Thread dump from the executor taking 3 hours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNXUW.png)

Answer (score 0):

Learn how to understand Spark UI. This book section can help get you started: https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-webui.html

From Spark UI you should be able to see how much data (in percentiles) was processed per stage / partition / node / etc. Newer Spark UI (starting from version 2.0) shows even more granular information under SQL tab. This helps you find data skew if it exists. There are numerous options to fight a data skew, and most of them are specific to your application. For instance, see how Facebook deals with data skew with adaptive partitioning:
https://www.slideshare.net/SparkSummit/handling-data-skew-adaptively-in-spark-using-dynamic-repartitioning

There's a possibility that you don't have a data skew, but one of your cluster nodes is "broken". This is the case if you see that it's the same node that happens to be slower than the others. We've seen such an anomaly in AWS environment. After killing the node, and starting a new one instead everything started working properly.